# Nodejs: Como evitar mensajes repetidos en webhook con Whatsapp Api Cloud?

Tags: nodejs, api, whatsapp, facebook-api, whatsapp-webhook

Tengo un webhook configurado en whatsapp api cloud, con un numero propio. Trabaje una aplicación en NodeJS Express y Typescript para poder escuchar los eventos de whatsapp a mi servidor.

El proyecto es un chatbot, cuando recibo un mensaje disparo ciertas acciones para contestar dependiendo del tipo de mensaje que reciba, una vez se valide esto se procesa la respuesta al mensaje que se recibió y luego se envía la respuesta por medio de un POST a la api de whatsapp  (`graph.facebook.com/v16.0/${ID_CELL}/messages` )

Segun la documentacion oficial de whatsapp debe recibir un status 200 por cada mensaje que envia

> Si enviamos una solicitud de webhook a tu punto de conexión y tu servidor responde con un código de estado HTTP que no es 200, o si no podemos entregar el webhook por otro motivo, seguiremos intentando cada vez con menos frecuencia hasta que la solicitud tenga éxito, por hasta 7 días.

[Referencia](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/set-up-webhooks/)

Lo cual intente, incluso retorno un status 200 del lado de mi servidor cuando ocurre un error, asi como Andres Lopez menciona en esta respuesta en donde cuenta una experiencia parecida [Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72894209/whatsapp-cloud-api-sending-old-message-inbound-notification-multiple-time-on-my)

Lo mismo comenta Shajeel Afzal Referencia [Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882393/whatsapp-business-api-webhook-getting-triggered-automatically)

Incluso encontre este foro en la comunidad de facebook que habla de retornar el status 200 [Referencia](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/536171925013455/)

Aunque las referencias esten en inglés, igual las adjunto por posible casos de uso.

Pero pese a que intente eso, aun sigo recibiendo mensajes repetidos y no se que más hacer para evitar esto, por favor si alguien me ayuda, a veces tiene un comportamiento en el que envía una respuesta repetido pasado un tiempo, no se que mas intentar. He estado investigando de como cerrar el webhook o tener un mayor control para evitar esto pero no encuentro nada

```
 export const receiveMessage = async(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

      let input = req.body.input[0];
      let changes = input.changes[0];
      let value = changes.value;
      let messageObject = value.messages;

      try{

          const messages: Message = messageObject[0];
          const from = message_object[0]?.from;

          //Type of message
          let typeMessage = messages.type;

          // First we record the log
          await registerEvents(entry, 200, "Receiving Webhook Whatsapp Api Cloud", null);

          // we validate that the message is not undefined
          if (messageObject === undefined) {
              console.log('no message found');
              res.sendStatus(200);
          }

          // we validate the type of messaging

          if (messageType === "text") {
              sendStatusMessage("Writing...", from);
              const data = await textProcess(messages, from);
              SendMessageWhatsApp(data);
              res.sendStatus(200);
          }

          if (messageType === "audio") {
              console.log('is audio');
              const data = await audioProcess(messages, from);
              SendMessageWhatsApp(data);
              res.sendStatus(200);
          }

          if (messageType === "button") {
              const data = await buttonProcess(messages, from);
              SendMessageWhatsApp(data);
              res.sendStatus(200);
          }

          if (messageType === "interactive") {
              const data = await interactiveProcess(messages, from);
              SendMessageWhatsApp(data);
              res.sendStatus(200);
          }



      } catch (error) {

          await registerEvents(input, 500, "Webhook Whatsapp Api Cloud Error", error)
          // Avoid lopp webhook
          console.log('An internal error occurred on the server but 200 should always be sent');
          res.sendStatus(200)
      }

}
```

Utilizo https de node para realizar las peticiones a la api de whatsapp y asi poder enviar el mensaje de respuesta

```
function SendMessageWhatsApp(message: any) {
      constant data = JSON.stringify(message);

      constant options = {
          host: "graph.facebook.com",
          path: `/v16.0/${ID_CELL}/messages`,
          method: "POST",
          body: data,
          headers: {
              "Content-type": "application/json",
              Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN_CLOUD_API_WSP}`
          }
      };
      const req = https.request(options, res => {
          res.on("data", d => {
              process.stdout.write(d);
          });
      });

      req.on("error", error => {
          console.error(error);
          supabase.from('records').insert([
              {
                  message: error,
                  status: 500,
                  task: "Error sending message to Whatsapp",
                  error: null
              }
          ]);
      });

      req.write(data);
      req.end();
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda. Estaré muy agradecida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiciste lo que te recomienda whatsapp en la documentación ?

[image: codigo 131047 de error que muestra la documentación de api cloud whatsapp]

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/support/error-codes

Si te fijas el código de respuesta es 400 lo cual indica que el problema lo tienes tu con respecto a la solicitud.

envía un mensaje de plantilla o texto sin formato como sugiere la documentación si pasaron las 24 horas del mensaje que te envió el cliente.

[image: documentación de la api acerca de conversaciones]
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/conversation-types

Debes leer mas la documentación para informarte ,se que es un camino que lleva tiempo pero muchas respuestas las encontraras ahi.

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por responderme, efectivamente ya habia leido sobre ello y aun enviando plantillas el tema sigue siendo el mismo, porque no se si ya es un tema de numero

Answer (score 2):

lo único que puedes hacer es manejar los webhook repetidos con los ids que te envian estos webhooks , dependiendo del tipo de mensaje es donde estará el wamid de mensaje ,cuando envías el mensaje la petición post te devuelve un wamid y si miras bien tus webhooks te envía el mismo wamid cuando es sent,delivered,read,entonces con esos ids debes validar para que no se guarden denuevo .
puedes enviar un status 401 a los mensajes repetidos para que no se caiga tu servidor y esos webhook no tengan efectos.
intenta en viar el codigo de status con este ejemplo  para que no se repita infinitamente la peticion, si no le pones el .send o . json la peticion que da dando vueltas infinitamente .
tienes que devolver algo a la peticion con .send o .json

```js
res.status(200).send("OK");
// o tambien
res.status(200).json("OK");
```

yo la estoy probando con un dominio estatico con ngrok y tiene un dashboard para ver las peticiones con los estados que devueve y todo eso.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Gracias por responderme, este sigue siendo mi dolor de cabeza. Verifico a traves del ID pero aun asi no me explico porque los mensajes se repiten. Es decir, entiendo que es porque Whatsapp no recibe un estado 200, pero se supone que se lo envio cada vez que se responde el mensaje. Ademàs que cada vez que se recibe o envia un mensaje recibo en los estado del webhook un estado fallido con código 131047, que dice que no se puede enviar un mensaje distinto después de las 24hrs

Comment: Y se supone que ese codigo solo se recibe si intentas enviar un mensaje antes de que él usuario sea el que comience la conversación. Lo cual no sucede porque es decir, el usuario comienza la conversación y el bot contesta con un mensaje del tipo texto.

Comment: Yo creo que de alli viene el problema porque si por cada mensaje que envio y recibo whatsapp me envia un estado fallido es como si no hubiera tenido respuesta lo que puede hacer que se me esten repitiendo los mensajes. Lo malo es que aunque pregunte en facebook no contestan